# Can we copy a file from Android shared storage to app's folder?

Tags: android, storage, android-permissions, android-11, scoped-storage

I think by the time now everybody is familiar with the latest storage changes that Android has introduced targeting api level 29+. For 29 they gave flags to optout from these storage changes.

For Android 11 are we allowed to copy a file from shared storage to app's private folder ?

```
     try {
            if (tempFolder.canWrite()) {
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, photoNamegagalery);
                values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
                values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
                Uri uri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
                OutputStream imageOutStream = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uri);



                String destinationImagePath = File.separator + photoNamegagalery;
                File source = new File(selectedImagePath);
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
                    Bitmap bitmap = ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(ImageDecoder.createSource(getContentResolver(), Uri.fromFile(source)));
                    try {
                        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, imageOutStream);
                    } finally {
                        imageOutStream.close();
                    }
                }
        }
```

Comment: `For Android 11 are we allowed to copy a file from shared storage to app's private folder ?` Yes. You can and you are allowed to do so. And you can do that without using the media store or bitmaps. You cannot use Bitmap class to copy a pdf file. Or a text.

Comment: One cannot use the media store to create files in apps private folders to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

on Android 11 you can't access files not in scope of your app (so-called "private folder"), without [special permission](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/manage-all-files#all-files-access). this opt-out flag was for this reason - you should implement as fast as you can some feature that moves your data from some folder in storage to your apps folder

for accessing photos/videos you can still use `MediaStore`

Comment: So we can't copy files from camera or pictures folder to our app's folder?

Comment: afaik these files should be able to read/copy using `MediaStore`

Comment: Yes that's true we can read these file using Mediastore api but we can't copy them to app's folder that we get using getExternFilesDir()

Comment: well, if you can open file and show on the screen then this `Bitmap` is already in your apps memory, so you can save this `Bitmap` as file in your folder

Comment: I have added the code above but on running the above code  the app creates  the file in the shared storage itself. Is there any other way. We can't change the RELATIVE_PATH

Comment: `afaik these files should be able to read/copy using MediaStore` @snachsms No need for media store. An app can read/copy them in the classic way to getExternalFilesDir() and such.